# Forcing iOS to run out of memory

Tags: ios, memory-management

I have spent the last 4 hours trying to get my iPad to run out of memory and I just can't make it happen.

Oh, the irony.

I want to testing some logging code, and I need to App the be killed for using too much memory but I can't make it happen, no matter how much memory I alloc.  I am using the following code to stress it out:

```
if (tempArray == nil)
    tempArray = [NSMutableArray array];

NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:malloc(10000000) length:10000000];

[tempArray addObject:data];
```

I run this every frame (30 times a second).  Eventually malloc just returns NULL, but I don't ever see memory warning like my testers are seeing.  tempArray is getting the NSData objects added to it.

I am running this on the device.  Is there a sure-fire way to get your App to use too much memory and be killed?

Comment: Did you find a way for forching an out of memory crash in foreground and backgroud?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try loading a large image multiple times and never release it, the same way you currently do with `NSData`.

Comment: OK, that worked.  Thanks, I assumed malloc would have done basically the same thing, but I guess not.

Comment: Tried this. Didn't work. Loaded an infinite with loading image. Doesn't run out of memory. Is there a way to test BOOM too? @sch

Answer (score 2):

You can simulate a low memory situation when using the simulator, the option can be found under the iOS Simulator 'Hardware' menu.

Comment: I don't need a warning, I need the App to be killed, the simulator only issues warnings.

Comment: If your app gets to the point where it will be killed, it's game over.  The intent is that you discard whatever you can in response to these warnings, and therefore avoid having your app killed.

Comment: Actually, I have some logging code I compile in that parses the console logs on the next start-up after a crash and I just needed this as a test case to make sure I was catching the out-of-memory case.  There is information in the logs from springboard that tells you why your app was killed and this was the data I wanted to make sure was logged.

Comment: Ah, that's a clever technique.

Comment: i don't see the options to simulate low memory situation in simulator, can you please more info on this, thanks

Comment: @Shaahul Select the Simulator app itself on your Mac (not Xcode), then under the Debug menu, you will see an option to Simulate Memory Warning (Shift Option M being the keyboard shortcut.)

Answer (score 1):

To increase memory pressure in Swift 5, you can create large `Data` instances. For example, this method wastes around 500 MB on each call:

```
static var wastedMemory: Data = Data()

static func waste() {
  let data = Data(repeating: 0, count: 500_000_000)
  wastedMemory.append(data)
}
```