# What if i want to create an object and memory in not availed in Swift 3/4?

Tags: swift, class, exception, memory-management

I want to create an object and have very less memory in RAM where object creation can't be possible, How to handle this condition? How can i get to know that object couldn't created? Is there any exception handling?

Example:

```
class MyClass{

   var array: [UInt64] = []

   init() {
       for num in 0..<100000000{
            array.append(num)
       }
   }

   func show(){
      forEach({ each in
          print(each)
      }) 
   }
}

let myClass: MyClass = MyClass()
myClass.show()
```

Comment: If your object can't be created because you run out of memory, don't worry, you'll know (probably because you'll crash).

Comment: How to handle before crash? Any exception?

Comment: Maybe  you can not got the count of available memory. Because OS could offer more memory than its really have by `Virtual Memory`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Forcing iOS to run out of memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9370086/forcing-ios-to-run-out-of-memory)

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you can't. Unless you're trying to allocate a huge object, chances are that any logic you'll try to execute will eventually try to allocate another object and also fail. And now you'll want to tackle this new situation which can lead to other allocation attempts, and so on...

Let it go. If there's no more RAM available then is expected for applications to crash. It's not your fault. What your app can do is to be a good citizen and don't waste memory. In the end if the device runs out of memory the OS starts killing apps that are in background and were not recently used, thus they don't execute code anyway.

Comment: "If there's no more RAM available then is expected for applications to crash. It's not your fault." how can i prevent it?

Comment: @sulabh you can avoid the device running out of memory. What your app can do is to be a good citizen and don't waste memory. In the end if the device runs out of memory the OS starts kiiling apps that are in background, thus they don't execute code anyway.

Comment: @sulabh typo above, wanted to say `you can't avoid the device running out of memory`, this is something out of your control